# Headset mic not working only in Windows 10 ASUS ROG laptop

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, asus-laptop

This is not the common *"I plugged the mic in the headphones jack"* error (sadly), I'll describe the scenario and then what I've tried.

- ASUS ROG G750JW laptop running Windows 10 Home version 1903 (updated yesterday)
- HyperX (Kingston) CLOUD HX-HSCL-SR/NA headset
- RealTek High Definition Audio card
- 2 input jacks (headphones and microphone)

**Problem**: Only the integrated laptop mic seems to work (and it works fine), as soon as I plug in the headset mic absolute silence is present. Tried this:

- use the headset in another computer (ubuntu, 2 connectors) and phone (iOS, 1 connector), it works perfect
- plug just the headphone and use the integrated laptop mic, it works fine (skype, zoom, chrome, etc)
- updated audio drivers manually using Driver Easy, no luck
- updated Windows, no luck
- allow all apps to use mic (from audio settings), no luck
- using "Stereo Mix", no luck
- basically all items [from this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/395296/fix-my-microphone-doesnt-work-on-windows-10/), no luck

**Interesting**:

- the mic jack seems to work since each time I connect it a dialog appears telling me I just connected something
- VirtualBox is installed and it doesn't works there neither (ubuntu vm), disabled audio from all vm's in case there was a conflict and guess what, no luck
- when pluggin/unpluggin the mic I can see the sound level indicator bars move briefly (the green bars in device management, in mic properties)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I needed it fixed ASAP I went for a solution instead of a fix.

The solution was to buy an [USB sound card](https://www.walmart.com/c/kp/usb-sound-cards), they are really really cheap (mine costed $3.50) and worked perfectly.

I believe Zoom had something to do with the problem since today it started to ignore the integrated mic too, but no time to dig deeper into the reasons why, it works now.